# Limites para update com BufferedReader no mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update

Olá pessoal bom dia, 
estou tendo problemas com uma rotina de update na base de dados mysql, estou lendo um BufferedReader contendo mais de 3.000.000 de registros e fazendo o update no mysql porém quando estou perto dos 1.200 primeiros registros o sistema apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
2015-08-21 20:27:12,512 ERROR Erro de IO: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at ar.com.qualaconsulting.AccountDataLoader.loadCF_Ids(AccountDataLoader.java:1387)
    at ar.com.qualaconsulting.AccountDataLoader.preprocess(AccountDataLoader.java:1717)
    at ar.com.qualaconsulting.TestDataLoader.main(TestDataLoader.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

O código referenciado é esse:

```
 InputStreamReader csv = new InputStreamReader(results, "UTF-8");

   BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(csv);
                //Busca a primeira linha que é o cabeçalho
                csvReader.readLine();

                String curLine =  null;

                logger.info("Vai Percorrer arquivo CSV");
                int totalArquivosAtualizados = 0;

                    while((curLine = csvReader.readLine()) != null){//loop vai começar na 2nd linha
                        try{
                            logger.info("SfID atualizado = "+totalArquivosAtualizados);
                            curLine = curLine.replace("\"", "");
                            String[] line = curLine.split(",");
                            String numCF = line[1];
                            String sfId = line[0];

                            logger.info("Update no MySql com ID da cadeia forçada.  numCF:" +numCF +" sfId:"+sfId);
                            cadeiaForcadaDao.updateSfID(Long.valueOf(numCF), sfId);
                            totalArquivosAtualizados++;
                            logger.info("Update no MySql FINALIZADO.");

                          }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                              this.logger.error("Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar a cadeia: ", e);
                          }catch(Exception e1){
                             this.logger.error("Ocorreu um uma exeção genérica: ", e1);
                          } 
                    }
                    if (csvReader != null) {
                        try {
                            logger.info("Fechando o arquivo csvReader!");
                            csvReader.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            this.logger.error("Erro de cono fechamento de arquivo .CSV =>" +e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    logger.info("Total de SfIDs atualizados = "+totalArquivosAtualizados);
              }
              logger.info("Gravação finalizada");
            }

        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            this.logger.error("Erro de conexão ao SF: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            this.logger.error("Erro de 'Encoding': " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.logger.error("Erro de IO: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            this.logger.error("Erro de Interrupção: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

A linha referenciada no erro (AccountDataLoader.java:1387) é justamente:

```
while((curLine = csvReader.readLine()) != null){
```

que é quando se está lendo arquivo, existem algum limite do BufferedReader  ou do Mysql para vários updates dessa forma?

Comment: Você está usando hibernate?

Comment: Não, estou usando jdbc/spring

Comment: Você pode postar o código desses métodos: ar.com.qualaconsulting.AccountDataLoader.loadCF_Ids()
ar.com.qualaconsulting.AccountDataLoader.preprocess()

Comment: @adelmo00 o método loadCF_Ids() é justamente código acima, simplifiquei porque ele faz outras buscas para preencher o results antes de ser adicionado no InputStreamReader. o erro acontece depois que atualiza alguns registros e não consegui mais passar para o proximo registro no csvReader.readLine(), pensei que o InputStreamReader estava corrompido porem usei um lineNumberReader para verificar o número de linhas e retornou mais de 3.000.000

Comment: Olhando aqui na web achei um tutorial para efetuar insert com Spring Batch a partir de um arquivo .CSV. Veja se pode te ajudar: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-csv-file-to-database/. Para o erro que ocorreu não encontrei nada ainda, assim que encontrar coloco resposta

Comment: Ok Obrigado adelmo dei uma olhada no seu tutorial porém não é o que eu procuro, o problema realmente é na leitura do conteúdo do BufferReader, porém chega uma hora que ele encontra esse erro e para de ler o resto do arquivo e por consequencia fazer o update no mysql. A principio pensei que fosse linha vazia no Buffer, mas quando uso o lineNumber ele passa por todos as linhas usando o mesmo csvReader.readLine(), por isso a dúvida